# What is the name of the "primary" carbon in a benzene derivative?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

If we have a benzene with a single substituent, such as chlorobenzene, what do we call the carbon atom to which the group is attached? I'm familiar with the ortho- meta- para- nomenclature, but the last one escapes me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's *ipso*-.

1. [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arene_substitution_patterns#Ipso.2C_meso.2C_and_peri_substitution)
2. IUPAC *[Gold Book](http://goldbook.iupac.org/index.html)* [definition of the *ipso*-attack](http://goldbook.iupac.org/I03251.html)